# Date changed after transfer from SQL Server 2000 to 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I transfered data from our old SQL Server 2000 (SBS 2003) to another server running SQL Server 2008 r2 (Server 2008 r2 standard).
The data was transfered, but now the dates in the different tables are messed up.
Is there a special procedure I need to follow in order for the date column to transfer correctly. If memory servers, date columns are soted as an offset.
Anyone know how to correct this?
I tried looking it up, but couldn't find an answer. Maybe I just didn't think of the correct key words.

Thanks!

**Edit:** What I mean by messed up is that the original date (from the old server) is 2011-05-08 and the new date (from the new server) is 2010-04-14. I tried to see if there is a common offset for all he moved dates, but couldn't find one.

Comment: How did you transfer the data? Are the table structures and column definitions the same?

Comment: Yes. They are the same. I transfered a backup of the old DB and restored it on the new server. Then I did insert...select, from the old DB to the new.

Comment: What do you mean "the dates are messed up"? Please provide specific examples.

Comment: @Martin - You're right. I'm sorry. Editing the question with a more specific description.

Comment: @Elad - did the insert...select do any formatting, or was it literally listing all of the columns out twice?

Comment: What datatype are the source and destination columns? What time component are in these values?

Comment: The columns in SQL Server 2008R2 wouldnt of got change to datetime2 dates by accident?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have the Old (2011 dates) / New (2010 dates) backwards? It sounds like you just aren't including the date column in your INSERT, and it has a default of GETDATE(), so it has the current date getting inserted. Or there is some trigger changing the value from what you specify to the current date. To verify, do your SELECT..INSERT into a new or temp table and see what you get.